# How to update TextView text after clicking a button

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

when i cick on number the TextView Doesnt change it supposed to show number when i click on them like the calculator
that's my code i still in the first part of the app

```
 fun clicknumber(view: View) {

        var buselected = view as Button
        var tvnum = tv.text.toString()
       if (newOp){
            tv.text = ""
       }
        newOp=false


        when (buselected.id) {
           one.id-> tvnum += "1"
            two.id-> tvnum += "2"
            three.id-> tvnum += "3"
            four.id-> tvnum += "4"
            five.id-> tvnum += "5"
            six.id-> tvnum += "6"
            seven.id-> tvnum += "7"
            eight.id-> tvnum += +"8"
            nine.id-> tvnum += "9"
            dot.id-> tvnum += "."
            minusplus.id -> tvnum = "-" + tvnum
        }
    }
}
```

i think the problem is in the "tvnum" and i wanna to clear the textview when i do a new operation, i write the code but it doesnt work so good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning`tvnum` but you're doing nothing with it. You need to set the text in the TextView instead.
`tv.text = tvnum`

Comment: but i write that         var tvnum = tv.text.toString()
i think that shold do it

Comment: @TiKoTech. `tvNum` is a local String variable that has nothing to do with your TextView. The TextView doesn't know anything about this variable unless you tell it to do something with it.

Comment: @Tiko Tech, No, it doesn't. You're assigning the TextView text to the tvnum.

Comment: ahh now i get but i see someone who do that (    tvnum += "5"     )and it work for him ... i take your advice and change my code to (  tv.text = tvnum +"1" ) what is the differance between that and that   (  tv.text = tvnum +="1" ) and how i use += in my code and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Honestly saying i can't understand your question but still you can try this...
Change the text of the view individually in each case.
like tv.text = "---"

Comment: i trying to "if i click on button "1" it appear 1 in the text view